# HTMLS/CSS Window size

Tags: html, css

Hey guys I need help with CSS. I don't know how to make my html template fit in browser window. Look at picture

Thats how not resized looks like:

http://s28.postimg.org/j2qkmmlqz/Untitled1.jpg

An thats how resized looks like

[image]

Here is the CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


body {
    width:auto;
    font: Trebuchet MS;
    background: #E6E6E6;
}

h1{
    font: Trebuchet MS;
}
#visainfo1 {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    padding-left: 50px;
}
#visainfo2 {
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
#info1 {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: white;
}
#info2 {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: white;
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
}
#info3 {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: white;
    float: right;
    width: 45%;
}
#info4 {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: white;
}
#info5 {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: white;
}

footer{
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 0; 
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="lt">
<title>Darbelis</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<body>
<div id="visavisa">
    <header id="banner">

        <h1>The Site</h1>
    </header>
    <nav id="menu_virsut">
        <ul>
            <li><a href >menu link</a></li>
            <li><a href >menu link</a></li>
            <li><a href >menu link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <section id="visainfo1">
        <section id="info1">
                <h2>Aenean ac diam nec neque fringilla</h2>
          <p>Integer eget mauris et urna pulvinar consectetur hendrerit eget mauris. Praesent a interdum justo. Aenean ac diam nec neque fringilla cursus. Donec iaculis tortor in nunc vehicula dfdftrum. Integer malesuada mollis ligula at varius</p>
          <p>Integer eget mauris et urna pulvinar consectetur       hendrerit eget mauris. Praesent a interdum justo. Aenean ac diam nec neque fringilla cursus. Donec iaculis tortor in nunc vehicula rutrum. Integer malesuada mollis ligula at variu</p>
        </section>
            <section id="info2">
                <p>Integer eget mauris et urna pulvinar consectetur hendrerit eget mauris. Praesent a interdum justo. Aenean ac diam nec nequeringilla cursus. Donec iaculis tortor in nunc vehicula rutrum. Integer malesuada mollis ligula at varius. Dorce pila meracone.</p>
            </section>
            <section id="info3">
                <p>Integer eget mauris et urna pulvinar consectetur hendrerit eget mauris. Praesent a interdum justo. Aenean ac diam nec nequeringilla cursus. Donec iaculis tortor in nunc vehicula rutrum. Integer malesuada mollis ligula at varius. Dorce pila meracone.</p>
            </section>
    </section>
    <section id="visainfo2">
        <section id="info4">
          <h2>New site!</h2>
                <p>Welcome to our new website. Please have a look around, any feedback is much appreciated.</p>
            </section><!---Uzdaro side bar item---->
        <section id="info5">
                <form action="MAILTO:.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
                First name:<br>
                <input type="text" name="name" value=""><br>
                Last name:<br>
                <input type="text" name="mail" value=""><br>
                Messege:<br>
                <input name="comment" type="text" value="" size="30"><br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Send">
                </form>
            </section>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <nav id="menu_foot">
            <ul>
                <li>menu link</li>
                <li>menu link</li>
                <li>menu link</li>
                <li>menu link</li>
                <li>menu link</li>
                <li>menu link</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
            <p id="footer_text">Nullam mattis luctus dolor, sed gravida tellus volutpat vel. Maecenas mollis augue sed tortor molestie ornare. Proin dapibus dictum eros ut adipiscing. Nullam ultrices dolor ut tristique sollicitudin. Integer scelerisque urna est, sit amet aliquet sapien accumsan quis. Nullam luctus semper vulputate. Nulla egestas urna nec tellus ultrices elementum. Proin dapibus dictum eros ut adipiscing. Nullam ultrices dolor ut tristique sollicitudin. Integer scelerisque</p>
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: the show html as well. the css is useless without being able to see WHAT it's styling.

Comment: nothing happens... same

Comment: The padding of your sections get added to your width in percent. You basically have 90% + 100px in total width. If the window width is < 1000px it is not going to work.

Comment: Yeah, @RomainBraun is right. To fix this you could use percentage based paddings.

Comment: Here's an example of using percentages instead. You'll want to modify them to your preference. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGyPeY

Comment: thnx @zsherman and post in on answers i will mark it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is occurring because your paddings are in pixels, but your widths are in percentages, like @RomainBraun mentioned in the comments.

To fix this, you can change your paddings to percentages. I've done this in a codepen: [codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGyPeY](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGyPeY) and you can see that it 'squishes' without dropping down to another line.

Example:

```
#visainfo1 {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    padding-left: 2%; //Percentage of the parent container's width!
}
```

Adjust the percentages to where the total width of your divs and their horizontal padding are less than 100%, and you should be good.

Comment: Just to add another possibility : if you want to keep fixed width paddings, look into the CSS calc() function. It allows you to have widths like these: calc(30%-50px). Could be convenient. Check the browser support first though. http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to / are not able to use media queries, changing #visainfo2 to

```
#visainfo2 {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  padding-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 49px;
}
```

Should solve your problem. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/86o4r7zj/) is a working example. It's real;ly basic but you should be able to twaek it to produce what you want